# Google API keep making network call

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-translate

When I include the javascript,

```
https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
```

I keep getting network calls to retrieve a file,

```
https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_static/img/loading.gif
```

[image]

How can I keep this from happening?

Comment: Can you show your javascript code please ?

Comment: Considering it's the Google library doing it, you can't.  Also, I wouldn't exactly worry about it since the request goes to a Google server and not to any of your own resources meaning its Google's bandwidth, not yours.